# If there is a like button next to each user, why could scrolling trigger random users' like buttons be highlighted?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I use self.like.alpha = 0.5 to grey out the like button next to the user who was liked. Scrolling causes the highlight to sometimes disappear and appear next to other users.

I've used self.like.alpha = 0.5 last various places in the code but it changes nothing.

```
@IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {

self.like.alpha = 0.5


       let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let keyToPost = ref.child("likes").childByAutoId().key




    ref.child("humans").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  {(snapshot) in

        if let humans = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let updateLikes: [String: Any] = ["humansWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]

            ref.child("humans").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) in



                if error == nil {
                    ref.child("humans").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        if let properties = snap.value as?[String: AnyObject]{
                            if let likes = properties["humansWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                let count = likes.count
                            let update = ["likes" : count]
                                ref.child("humans").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(update)





                            }

                        }

                    })
                }
            })

        }

    })


    ref.removeAllObservers()



}
```

What I need is for the like button that is clicked to be greyed out. It has to stay greyed out and the greying out should not jump to another user's like button.

/Updated code after 1st answer

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let like = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton


    let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    let person: Userx = humans[indexPath.row]





    cell.lblName.text = person.Education

    cell.postID = self.humans[indexPath.row].postID


    if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
        let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
        immy.sd_setImage(with: url)


    }




    return cell



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that tableView cells are reusable. When you dequeue one, you cannot assume anything about the existing values. If you mark a cell liked (with button formatting), when that cell is reused, the formatting is still there.

When you dequeue a cell in your cellForRowAt function, you need to reset all the values according to your data store.

I am having a little trouble understanding your database design/usage, but based on the code you added to the post:

```
let currUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid // better to add this as a VC level variable as you will do this lookup a lot.
let likeArray = person.humansWhoLike ?? [] 
let likeStatus = likeArray.contains(currentUser) 
//from your code, 'like' is the button to be formatted
like.alpha = likeStatus ? 0.5 : 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a dequeReusableCell already, but I am not sure how to incorporate that code in there because like is not a member of my dataArray (ie humans). And even if it is, it doesn't work. I am adding that part of the code to the question. Do you maybe know how to incorporate yours into that?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have two questions. Since this is using the status of person.humansWhoLike and not the clicking action, is there a way to ensure that it only fades out if the like action was done within 24 hours? Second, is I get error of Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'String' in line 2. I am researching how to fix that. Do you know how? I had set humansWhoLike to a String? previously.

Comment: To have it fade that way, you would need to track a date stamp of each like. That could be done in the humansWhoLike object, or in a separate array or dictionary so you can discard the information when it is no longer relevant. You can try casting the array as `let likeStatus = person.humansWhoLike as? [String] ?? []`